# Не отлавливает try catch на обычном Exception

Tags: c#, httpclient

Ссылка:`https://guidebrand.ru/mark/bathing-ape`
Метод который не ловит ошибку в `foreach`
Ошибка должна выпасть сразу в `foreach` т.к `document.QuerySelectorAll("ul.contact-list li") = null`

```
public async Task searchLink(string itemLink)
        {

            string htmlSitelink = await client.GetStringAsync(itemLink);
            var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(htmlSitelink));

            try
            {
                foreach (var site in document.QuerySelectorAll("ul.contact-list li"))
                    if (site.TextContent.Contains("Веб-сайт"))
                        siteLink = site.QuerySelector("a").GetAttribute("href");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{itemLink}\r\nНету ссылки на сайт");
                siteLink = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не помогло. значение возвращается null, ошибка не выскакивает. И при всем при этом этот null не вызывает дальше ошибки

Comment: Понял, он у меня в конструторе, поэтому без await был

Comment: обновил вопрос, метод вызывается с await, так же на `foreach` пропускает. Уточню, метод вызывается в `async` методе

Comment: А почему IEnumerable вдруг вернёт null? Он вернёт пустой список. Не помю что бы хоть один из известных методов который возвращает IEnumerable-совметимый тип давал null.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема из-за `async void`. Замените на `async Task`.

Уберите все `.Result`. Поставьте `await`. Вместо одной строки будет несколько.

Ещё лучше переписать метод следующим образом:

```
public async Task<string> SearchLink(string itemLink)
{
    var httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(itemLink);
    var htmlSitelink = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(htmlSitelink));

    try
    {
        foreach (var site in document.QuerySelectorAll("ul.contact-list li"))
        {
            if (site.TextContent.Contains("Веб-сайт"))
            {
                return site.QuerySelector("a").GetAttribute("href");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{itemLink}\r\nНету ссылки на сайт");
    }
    return "";
}
```

Вызываем так:

```
siteLink = await SearchLink("...");
```